# Question on a hypothesis test

Tags: probability, statistics

So I have population mean (for average production on some farms) = $3000$, and a test for a new fertilizer has sample size $n = 70$, sample mean = $3120$, sample standard deviation = $578$.

The company making the fertilizer claims that it knows that the fertilizer improves the production. Perform the appropriate test with a significance level of $0.05$.

So I computed the test statistic
$$\frac{3120 - 3000}{\frac{578}{\sqrt{70}}} = 1.73 \ ,$$
and since this is a one-sided test, we will compare with the respective normal quantile for 0.95 $= 1.96$.

Now is the correct null hypothesis $H_0: μ>3000$ or $H_0:μ \leq 3000$ (versus their respective negations)? And, whichever the case is, which is the correct rejection region?

Comment: No, the null hypothesis should be the more conservative position that the new fertilizer does not improve production.

Comment: @littleO I see, so the rejection region is ${z > 1.96}$ and therefore we cannot reject $H_0 : μ=<3000$ ?

Comment: If it is an unilateral test you should not use the bilateral value of $1.96$. Furthermore, if you have the sample standard deviation (and not the population), you should use t-Student.

Comment: @Ertxiem As for t-student, you might be correct, but we haven't learned it yet, so the exercise is meant to be solved along these lines. Second, what value should I use since the test is unilateral?

Comment: I'm assuming that you have a table for the Normal distribution. The value of $1.96$ corresponds to 2.5% of the $z$ values above it (and 2.5% of the $z$ values below $-1.96$, for a total of 5%). If you look into the table, you should find a value of $z$ that has 5% of the values above it.

Comment: Ohhh I see, I got confused with a previous example... thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The population standard deviation is not known, so *looking ahead,* you should understand that this situation really should be analyzed using a t test. However, for for such a large sample size as $n = 70,$ you can get by assuming that the population SD is $\sigma=578.$

**T test--Population SD unknown:** Here is a printout of the exact t test from Minitab (slightly edited for relevance).

```
One-Sample T 

Test of μ = 3000 vs > 3000

 N    Mean  StDev  SE Mean      T      P
70  3120.0  578.0     69.1   1.74  0.043
```

(a) From printed t-tables, the 5% critical value for this one-sided t test is $c = 1.667;$
because $T = 1.74 > 1.667,$ you can reject $H_0: \mu = 5000.$

(b) From computer output, you can reject $H_0$ because the P-value 0.43 is *less than* 5%.

**Z test--Population SD assumed:** For comparison, this is a printout for your approximate z test. Here you have to "lie to the software," entering the sample standard $S = 578$ as if it were the population SD $\sigma.$ The (slightly edited) output is as follows:

```
One-Sample Z 

Test of μ = 3000 vs > 3000
The assumed population standard deviation = 578

 N    Mean  SE Mean       Z      P
70  3120.0     69.1    1.74  0.041
```

(a) From printed normal tables, the 5% critical value for this one-sided z test is $c = 1.645;$
because $T = 1.74 > 1.645,$ you can reject $H_0: \mu = 5000.$

(b) From computer output, you can reject $H_0$ because the P-value 0.41 is less than 5%.

---

**Summary:** Either way, the observed mean $\bar X = 3120$ is enough larger than
the hypothetical population mean $\mu = 3000$ to reject the null hypothesis $H_0: \mu = 3000$ against the one-sided alternative $H_a: \mu > 3000$.

However, if the "z statistic" had turned out to be $Z = 1.650$ (between 1.667 and 1.645), then the "z test" would reject $H_0$ (just barely) and the t test would not. So if you're testing exactly at a particular significance level, the approximate z test is not always a good substitute for the t test--even with s sample size as large as 70.

Also, there can be a big difference between a one-sided test and a two-sided test: For your data, a test against a two-sided alternative $H_a:  \mu \ne 3000$ would
have a P-value of about 8% and you could not reject at the 5% level.
[By doing a one-sided test, you are, in effect,  *ignoring the possibility* that
the new fertilizer might be worse.]